AutofillClientController leaking activity: system leak or is it my implementation?
When rotating the emulator the memory leak below pops up. I'm not able to figure out exactly where it comes from. To me it looks like the systems AutofillClientController is leaking my ExampleActivity. Any thoughts are appreciated!
Tested on:

Pixel 7 Pro API 34
Pixel 4 API 31
Pixel 3a API 28
Pixel 4 API 21 (report is slightly different, but I think the cause is the same)
LeakCanary 2.13

┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.provider.FontsContract class
│    Leaking: NO (ExampleApplication↓ is not leaking and a class is
│    never leaking)
│    ↓ static FontsContract.sContext
├─ com.example.ExampleApplication instance
│    Leaking: NO (Application is a singleton)
│    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    ↓ Application.mLoadedApk
│                  ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.LoadedApk instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 206.8 kB in 4052 objects
│    mApplication instance of com.example.
│    ExampleApplication
│    Receivers
│    ..ExampleApplication@321728936
│    ....VisibilityTracker@329242680
│    ....aF@329242760
│    ....d@329242824
│    ....RF@329242896
│    ....ProxyChangeListener$ProxyReceiver@329242968
│    ↓ LoadedApk.mServices
│                ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.util.ArrayMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 203.2 kB in 4011 objects
│    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
│               ~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 203.2 kB in 4009 objects
│    ↓ Object[2]
│            ~~~
├─ android.app.ContextImpl instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 6.2 kB in 86 objects
│    mOuterContext instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    ContextImpl.mOuterContext == ContextImpl.this: not tied to any particular
│    lifecycle
│    ↓ ContextImpl.mAutofillClient
│                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.autofill.AutofillClientController instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 26 B in 1 objects
│    mActivity instance of com.example.ui.ExampleActivity
│    with mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ AutofillClientController.mActivity
│                               ~~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.example.ui.ExampleActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.ui.ExampleActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback
​     and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 51.8 kB in 1004 objects
​     key = a1f4ff6a-48ea-4ba9-90c4-7f746b99af89
​     watchDurationMillis = 7757
​     retainedDurationMillis = 2755
​     mApplication instance of com.example.ExampleApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 34
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.13
App process name: com.example
Class count: 35752
Instance count: 351728
Primitive array count: 189083
Object array count: 44181
Thread count: 64
Heap total bytes: 39264516
Bitmap count: 35
Bitmap total bytes: 2247331
Large bitmap count: 0
Large bitmap total bytes: 0
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=166095,misses=321890,hitRate=34%]
RandomAccess[bytes=15827352,reads=321890,travel=107139495512,range=47678011,size
=58241724]
Analysis duration: 26210 ms


Agreed, that feels like a leak caused by the framework.

it would be helpful if you can share the activity code please
